# How to add a new object into the empty array I included in my profile model(mongodb/mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is my Profile model,

```
const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  company: String,
  website: String,
  location: String,
  status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  skills: {
    type: [String],
    required: true,
  },
  bio: String,
  githubusername: String,
  experience: [
    {
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      company: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      location: String,
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
      },
      to: Date,
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      description: String,
    },
  ],
  education: [
    {
      school: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      degree: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      fieldofstudy: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      from: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
      },
      to: Date,
      current: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      description: String,
    },
  ],
  social: {
    youtube: {
      type: String,
    },
    twitter: {
      type: String,
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String,
    },
    linkedin: {
      type: String,
    },
    instagram: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  posts: [],
});
```

And this is how I add a new post,

```
router.post(
  "/",
  [auth, [check("text", "Text is required").not().isEmpty()]],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    try {
      const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select("-password");

      let profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });
      if (profile) {

        const newPost = new Post({
          text: req.body.text,
          name: user.name,
          avatar: user.avatar,
          user: req.user.id,
        });

        const post = await newPost.save();
        profile.posts.unshift(post);
        res.json(post);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).json({ errors: [{ msg: "Server Error" }] });
    }
  }
);
```

Most of these work without any problems, I am able to add a new post without any error, But the post is not added to the posts array in my profiles. The end result I want is to keep a record of the user's posts so I can show them individually on his profile. Why isn't this working? Please Help me! I'm new to web development and I'm so confused about this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you haven't save the profile yet

Comment: No I mean if I have an existing account that I can access.

Comment: I found my mistake,thank you very much.Rookie mistake lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i understood by your question is you want to add post to profile schema.

```
const post = await newPost.save();
profile.posts.unshift(post);
await profile.save();
res.json(post);
```

You need to call save as well, you missed it. Now post will be pushed to profile collection in posts field.

Answer (score 1):

First step is to check your auth middleware if you are receiving a params of token,  second is to check if that token is valid. last is to check your "router.post" logic.

Comment: I found the issues,while I'm saving the post,I'm not actually saving the updated profile.Thanks for your help!